# Google sheets script: range number not work

Tags: spreadsheet

Why a range writed in this way not work?

```
function Copiarisultati() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange(18,3,0,1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange(15,3,0,1).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in this code:

1. You are not getting a Sheet object.
2. when using `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`, numRows cannot be zero. If it numRows is zero, you are refering nothing. The minimum value should be 1.

Explaination:
SpreadsheetApp.getActive() is returning a Spreadsheet Object, but not a Sheet object. Check this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActive()

So In your case, instead of using `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`, please use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`. (If you are refering to your exsiting active Sheet)

```
function Copiarisultati() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var val = spreadsheet.getRange('C1').getValue();
  spreadsheet.getRange(18,3,0,1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange(15,3,0,1).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Notice there are many ways to reference a sheet without using "Active".

If I want to reference a sheet call "Sheet2" in a Spreadsheet,
one example would be:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("the Spreadsheet url").getSheetByName("Sheet2")
...
```

Please study this documentation for more info:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

Comment: And if I have to choose a range on another sheets, how can I do using numbers? fro exemple 
spreadsheet.getRange(sheet1!18,3,1,1)

Comment: You should use `var otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('your other sheet name')`. And then `otherSheet.getRange(18,3,1,1)`.